# Future<dynamic> is not subtype of type String? flutter Err

Tags: flutter, dart, sharedpreferences

I have an err in my app. I can't read data from shared perfrences in flutter

**my code**

```
TextFormField(
              enabled: false,
             initialValue:  Data.getData(key: 'phone_number'),
                    maxLength: 14,
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.phone,
                    textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.deepPurple),
                      ),
                      suffixIcon: Icon(
                        Icons.phone_android_sharp,
                        color: Colors.deepPurple,
                      ),
                      border: OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0)),
)),
```

**my getData func**

```
static getData({key}) async {
    final perf = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    var data = perf.getString(key);
    print(data);
    return data.toString();
  }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a Future and how do I use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63017280/what-is-a-future-and-how-do-i-use-it)

Comment: Getting data from shared preferences is an async operation, so take a look at [FutureBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare a variable initialValue and then assign it the value by calling the function getData to it as follows:-

```
String initialValue='';
@override
void initState(){
   super.initState();
   initializeData();
}

void initializeData()async{
  setState((){
    initialValue=await Data.getData(key: 'phone_number');
  });
}
```

and then simply put this initialValue in your below code as:-

```
TextFormField(
              enabled: false,
             initialValue:  initialValue,
                    maxLength: 14,
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.phone,
                    textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.deepPurple),
                      ),
                      suffixIcon: Icon(
                        Icons.phone_android_sharp,
                        color: Colors.deepPurple,
                      ),
                      border: OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0)),
)),
```

Answer (score 1):

As you are returning a `String` value and since you haven't specified the return type you are getting this error.

Please replace your current `getData` function with the below function, hopefully, this should fix the issue.

```
static Future<String> getData({key}) async {
    final perf = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    var data = perf.getString(key);
    print(data);
    return data.toString();
  }
```